# Possible to remove ecommerce_event from being reported as revenue on Firebase Console (iOS)

Tags: ios, firebase, in-app-purchase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

When we started using Fabric we created an **ecommerce_purchase** event to track and report on all in app purchases.

We then implemented Firebase. We continued to use the **ecommerce_purchase** event because firebase was not reporting iOS in app purchases yet.

*Now* Firebase does report "*some*" of the in app purchases, but not yet all of them (subscription renewals are a large part of our revenue, and not yet handled by Firebase).

The **ecommerce_purchase** event is still reporting correctly, but our issue is the console now double reports quite a bit due to the revenue numbers automatically combining the **ecommerce_purchase** event, as well as the firebase automatically tracked **in_app_purchase** event.

Long story short... is there a way to exclude one of these events from the revenue numbers reported by Firebase in the console?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to exclude the events in the reporting. What you can do is to export your analytics data to BigQuery and perform custom analysis there. Follow the instructions here to [link Firebase to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en).